# How to manage roles and queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am creating an admin panel with 4 roles. Admin has permission to all data. Organizer role has access to his data. and 3rd role has access to those data that organizer allows. and 4rth Role has access that 3rth role allows.

In CRUD operation I gets current user Id using this code:

```
var currentUser = Guid.Parse(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.GetUserId());
```

and passed this Id to data access layer. If current user is the owner of desired entity, then CRUD operation will act.
In data access leyer I checkes if current user Id matches UserId of the entity then it lets do the operation:

```
 var product=_dbContext.Products.Where(x=>x.UserId==currentUser && x.ProductId== productId);
```

But I want Admin be able to do these operations too. I know that I can write multiple methods to do same operation based on current user Role. But is there any cleaner solution to do?

For example Organizers can edit a product with id=1, because he is the owner of that product with id =1. But I want, Also Admin be able to edit product with id=1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this...

```
var rolesForUser = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser);
Product product;

if (rolesForUser.Contains("Admin"))
{
    product = _dbContext.Products.Where(x.ProductId == productId);
}
else
{
    product = _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUser && x.ProductId == productId);
}
```